# self executing function arguments

Tags: javascript, jquery

In order to prevent prototype.js conflicts with jquery I wrapped my jquery code in the following snippet:

```
(function($) {

})(jQuery);
```

If I understood this correnctly, `$ === jQuery` would be true inside my function. But is the actual "in parameter" `jQuery` in this case, which gets the alias `$` inside my function?

If my assumption is correct, do I need to pass `jQuery` on both places in order to call it `jQuery`, or would it be ok to just pass it at the end of the function?

Comment: `$` is the parameter name, and the variable `jQuery` (it could be any expression) is what you pass in as an argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within your IIFE you can use either `$` or `jQuery` - they're both in scope.

Only the `(jQuery)` is actually being passed as an *argument* - the `$` is just the function *parameter* (and therefore aliased to `jQuery`).

To see that, your code is *almost* equivalent to:

```
var f = function($) {
    ...
};

f(jQuery);
```

except that your IIFE is an anonymous function.

Comment: Thank you, just the explanation I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

> If I understood this correnctly, $ === jQuery would be true inside my function. But is the actual "in parameter" jQuery in this case, which gets the alias $ inside my function?

Yes. `$` is the parameter name, and the variable `jQuery` is what you pass in as an argument - it could be any expression.

> If my assumption is correct, do I need to pass jQuery on both places in order to call it jQuery, or would it be ok to just pass it at the end of the function?

Yes, you would need to rename the parameter. Only it doesn't make much sense then, as you could just refer to the global `jQuery` variable then (unless you plan to overwrite that, e.g. with a different jQuery version) - the `$` alias is only for brevity. If you want to avoid confusion with Prototype, use `jQ` instead.

Comment: Thank you. Followup question: If I want to access something inside the closure from the outside, would I have to `return` it from inside of the closure first?

Comment: Yes, either `return` it or assign it to something that is accessible from outside (e.g. a global variable).

Answer (score 0):

Inside the closure, only `$` reliably references the jQuery library; more specifically, the library version at that point in time.

When another version of the library is loaded afterwards, only `$` still points to what you expect; the `jQuery` symbol would have been replaced by the latter version.

If you wish to use the `jQuery` alias inside the function you would need to rename `$` to `jQuery` in the function arguments.